# This error arise Renderig Problems couldn't resolve resource @id/panelDisplayDirection

Tags: java, android, xml

(2 sismilar errors not shown)
A  tag allows a layout file to dynamically include different layouts at runtime.At layout editing time the specific layout to be used is not
knouw. You can choose which layout you would like previewed while editing the layout.

```
     -<fragment com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment.....> (Pick Layout)
```

Do not warn about  tags in this session

The graphics preview in the layout editor may not be accurate:

```
     - Different corner sizes are not supported in Path.addRoundRect. (Ignore for this session)
```

Ignore all fidelity warnings for this session

Please suggest the solution i have tried many solutions but still not working , i hava 2Go ram. The program for GPS application was working fine when i run it in my phone but when in Android studio this error comes. thanks in advance :)

Comment: HELLO!!!  any one can answer me!!

Comment: Your question is not too clear. How much of your question is a quote of the error message? Under which circumstances do you get the error? What were you doing? What program for GPS were you using; was it something you wrote yourself, a libray, etc. And where do remarks like "Ignore all fidelity warnings for this session" come in?